# Div with display block causes the inline-block parent to get out of line

Tags: html, css, block

I would like to understand this weird behaviour, I have a div wrapping another div. 
parent is display inline block , and child is display none or block inside, whenever the child is block - the parent go down from the line, see example below: 
this is display none in child: 
[image]

and this is display block [image]

adding the CSS of the parent: 
[image]

can anyone explain please this behaviour?

Comment: Put your html and css code here.

Comment: Please provide some code or a JS fiddle with this problem highlighted. It is nearly impossible to help you with the screenshots you've provided

Comment: make the child `inline-block` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When use `display:inline-block`, add `vertical-align:top;`

Answer (score 1):

`display:block` pushes the element to a new line. When you say display of child is `none`, it tries to fit the element inline with other elements. Hence such a behaviour is observed.

[Check this link for detail on display property of css](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)